# ASP MVC - many request at one Ajax.BeginForm click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have question about requests - their count.
Im using `Ajax.BeginForm` and `onSuccess` option.
But when I click that form my JS handler for `OnSuccess` option fires up many times.
I looked up for my request and its looks like this:
[Image with number of request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8FEc.png)

So my question is: why if I click on AjaxForm it makes many request?
Thanks

View with Ajax action link:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.Accepted == false)
    {
        <text>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Accepted)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsOrganizer)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerRating)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Akceptuj", // <-- Text to display
                     "AcceptPlayer", // <-- Action Method Name
                     new { id = item.PlayerId },
                     new AjaxOptions
                     {
                         HttpMethod = "POST",

                     })
                </td>
            </tr>
        </text>
    }
}
```

Controller action:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult AcceptPlayer(long id)
{
    using (var Players = new DbMigrationExample2Entities())
    {
        Player playerToAccept = Players.Player.Find(id);
        if (playerToAccept == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        playerToAccept.Accepted = true;
        Players.SaveChanges(); return View();
    }
```

Comment: Could You provide the front-end code as well the Controller action?

Comment: The main post is updated with code sample

Comment: Change your Ajax.ActionLink into Html.ActionLink like Html.ActionLink(article.Title,
    new { controller = "Akceptuj", action = "AcceptPlayer",
          id = item.PlayerId })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have included **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js** twice once in the layout once in the partial. So your browser executes the js inside twice which will subscribe twice on the form click event that is why doing two POST instead of one.
So you need to remove the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js from the partial.

**Note:** If your are using a partial with a layout you don't need to duplicate the js included in the partial because it's already done by the layout. There are some good articles about layouts and partials.

**Second think if problem persist then the solution here** : 
[First ajax request is sent multiple times](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4373)

If nigher this all solution is not working in your case then definitely you need to change your **Ajax.ActionLink** into **Html.ActionLink**  Like :

```html
@Html.ActionLink(article.Title, new { controller = "Akceptuj", action = "AcceptPlayer", id = item.PlayerId }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })
```

**Cheers !!**